# Reading data from serial and displaying bytes image on tkinter

Tags: python, byte

I am reading data from serial port and i want to display images on tkinter by converting bytes data to image. how can i do that?
here is my code

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg='gray')
root.geometry('900x500')

with open('cccc.txt') as f:
    recentpacket = f.readlines()
    for i in recentpacket:
        recentpacketstring = i.rstrip('\n')
        recentpacketstring = recentpacketstring[0:29]

        line_a = recentpacketstring[0:29]

        if recentpacketstring.startswith('A'):
            result = bin(int(line_a,16))

            c = result[6:]
            d.append(c)

cc = list(map(list, zip(*d)))[::-1]
for i, b in enumerate (cc):
    ab = ''.join(b).replace('1','.').replace('0','')
    ba = ab.encode()
    image = tk.PhotoImage(data = ba)
    label = tk.Label(root, image=image, padx=20, pady=20)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

#variable ba contains this type of data:
b' \x1b[41m\x1b[31m.\x1b[0m\x1b[41m\x1b[31m.\x1b[0m\x1b[41m\x1b[31m.\x1b[0m                \x1b[41m\x1b[31m.\x1b[0m\x1b[41m\x1b[31m.\x1b[0m '

and this code give me this error:
TclError: couldn't recognize image data

i am very new to python, please help.